# Nginx FPM PHP Ubuntu $_POST not being populated

Tags: fastcgi, php

I have a server with NGNIX and PHP setup. The php script doesn't seem to have $_POST variable populated. I have checked the usual suspects, NGINX configuration, PHP.ini, etc. Not sure what I am doing wrong

```
location /ffc {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    index index.html index.php;
    root /var/www/;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass_request_body on;
        fastcgi_pass_request_headers on;
        fastcgi_param REQUEST_BODY $request_body;
    }
}



<?php

   var_dump($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
   var_dump($file= file_get_contents('php://input'));
   var_dump($_REQUEST);
   var_dump($GLOBALS);
   echo 'HEADERS <br/>';
   var_dump(get_headers());
?>
```

string(64) "fullname=test email=john@gmail.com message=dfadfsasdfas" array(0) { } array(8) { ["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]=> string(64) "fullname=test email=john@gmail.com message=dfadfsasdfas" ["_GET"]=> array(0) { } ["_POST"]=> array(0) { } ["_COOKIE"]=> array(7) { ["uid"]=> string(24) "CqQw7lMQ9JNQwkpwAwMpAg==" ["_vis_opt_s"]=> string(2) "1|" ["_vis_opt_test_cookie"]=> string(1) "1" ["mp_f6e7292aa77905eaaf9137d271097d72_mixpanel"]=> string(144) "{"distinct_id": "1447a3b515f188-069aadc7a-1b10435d-1fa400-1447a3b51603ef","$initial_referrer": "$direct","$initial_referring_domain": "$direct"}" ["ip"]=> string(13) "" ["iso2"]=> string(0) "" ["iso3"]=> string(0) "" } ["_FILES"]=> array(0) { } ["GLOBALS"]=> *RECURSION* ["_SERVER"]=> array(41) { ["USER"]=> string(8) "www-data" ["HOME"]=> string(8) "/var/www" ["FCGI_ROLE"]=> string(9) "RESPONDER" ["QUERY_STRING"]=> string(0) "" ["REQUEST_METHOD"]=> string(4) "POST" ["CONTENT_TYPE"]=> string(10) "text/plain" ["CONTENT_LENGTH"]=> string(2) "64" ["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]=> string(34) "/var/www/test/ffc/sendmail.php" ["SCRIPT_NAME"]=> string(17) "/ffc/sendmail.php" ["REQUEST_URI"]=> string(17) "/ffc/sendmail.php" ["DOCUMENT_URI"]=> string(17) "/ffc/sendmail.php" ["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=> string(17) "/var/www/test" ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]=> string(8) "HTTP/1.1" ["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]=> string(7) "CGI/1.1" ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]=> string(12) "nginx/1.5.10" ["REMOTE_ADDR"]=> string(13) "" ["REMOTE_PORT"]=> string(4) "1572" ["SERVER_ADDR"]=> string(13) "" ["SERVER_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" ["SERVER_NAME"]=> string(12) "test.com" ["REDIRECT_STATUS"]=> string(3) "200" ["PATH_INFO"]=> string(17) "/ffc/sendmail.php" ["REQUEST_BODY"]=> string(64) "fullname=test email=john@gmail.com message=dfadfsasdfas" ["HTTP_HOST"]=> string(12) "test.com" ["HTTP_ACCEPT"]=> string(74) "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]=> string(17) "gzip,deflate,sdch" ["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]=> string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.8" ["HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL"]=> string(9) "max-age=0" ["HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"]=> string(10) "text/plain" ["HTTP_COOKIE"]=> string(344) "uid=CqQw7lMQ9JNQwkpwAwMpAg==; _vis_opt_s=1%7C; _vis_opt_test_cookie=1; mp_f6e7292aa77905eaaf9137d271097d72_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%221447a3b515f188-069aadc7a-1b10435d-1fa400-1447a3b51603ef%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; ip=; iso2=; iso3=" ["HTTP_ORIGIN"]=> string(19) "http://test.com" ["HTTP_REFERER"]=> string(36) "http://test.com/ffc/contact.html" ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]=> string(120) "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36" ["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]=> string(14) "192.195.83.183" ["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT"]=> string(2) "80" ["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO"]=> string(4) "http" ["HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH"]=> string(2) "64" ["HTTP_CONNECTION"]=> string(10) "keep-alive" ["PHP_SELF"]=> string(17) "/ffc/sendmail.php" ["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]=> float(1394500698.6063) ["REQUEST_TIME"]=> int(1394500698) } ["_REQUEST"]=> array(0) { } } HEADERS 
NULL POST
array(0) { }